# Need help in putting not equal to field in SOSL in Salesforce

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I have created the below SOSL for my Apex class as per the req to return the queried valued
from the data base , but i am not able to put the not equal to operator in below SOSL,

i have tried the approach but getting , unexpected token in the return
kindly help in below SOSL.

SOSL Query :-

```
sQuery= 'FIND \''+sampleSearchText+ '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Literature__c('+
                    'Id,Name,RecordTypeName__c,Document_Type__c,Frequency__c'+
                    ' WHERE (Name LIKE \''+sample+'\' OR Document_Type__c LIKE \''+sample +
                    '\') '+
                    'AND isActive__c = true ORDER BY Name)';
```

need to put the RecordTypeName__c not equal to 'Servicing'

tried below approach

```
sQuery= 'FIND \''+sampleSearchText+ '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Literature__c('+
                    'Id,Name,RecordTypeName__c,Document_Type__c,Frequency__c'+
                    ' WHERE (Name LIKE \''+sample+'\' OR Document_Type__c LIKE \''+sample +
                    '\') '+
                    'AND (isActive__c = true AND RecordTypeName__c NOT Like Servicing  ORDER BY Name)';
```

Error :-

```
 {"status":500,"body":{"exceptionType":"System.QueryException","isUserDefinedException":false,"message":"unexpected token: '!'","stackTrace":"Class.subscriptionContactController.searchForMarketingOption: line 19, column 1"},"headers":{}}
```

Kinldy help on above issue

Comment: what type of field is RecordTypeName__c. Is it picklist?

Comment: its a text field

Comment: Put quotes around the value... `RecordTypeName__c != 'Servicing'`. You also should use bindings for the search string values or at least encode single quotes to avoid SOSL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes as mentioned by @PhilW, You have to enclose the servicing in single quotes. Please find the below sample SOSL query.                                                                                  `FIND {sample} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name), Contact(FirstName,LastName,LEADSOURCE WHERE Lastname != 'sample')`